# QGIS plugins for creating circular route on footpath network

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, network, cost-path

I'm looking for a way to create random circular walks of a specified distance from a given point. The end result will be similar to https://routeshuffle.com/ and http://www.routeloops.com/, but along a right of way network with cost surfaces tailored to walking.

I'm able to create a path between two points easily using least cost path, and could create random points to imitate a circular route; however I'm hoping there's a tool out there that will enable me to generate this random circular path without requiring these intermediate points.

Comment: me thinks this will be a killer app in the time of covid19